# How can I change the Kubuntu 12.04 default arguments for package unclutter?

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, cursor

Kubuntu 12.04 comes with unclutter which causes the mouse cursor (pointer) to disappear after 1 second of being stationary. I find this most annoying. Where can I change the idle time setting and other settings Kubuntu specifies for unclutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Kubuntu**

The package unclutter : http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/unclutter is not part of the kubuntu-desktop : http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/kubuntu-desktop.

That is, at here, with the new Kubuntu 12.04 beta installation:

> :~$ unclutter
>
> The program 'unclutter' is currently not installed.  You
>   can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install unclutter

**Unclutter**

- You could uninstall the package unclutter
- If you don't want to remove the package - the man pages are telling: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/unclutter.1.html

**Q:**

> I have seen gives me any clue as to where unclutter puts the config
>   file. That's my question, basically. Where is the config file?

**A:**
Installing the unclutter and looking what the package is installing:

```
dpkg -L unclutter
```

The output - you could use the Muon or the Synaptic to show this :

```
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90unclutter
/usr/share/doc/unclutter/copyright
/usr/share/doc/unclutter/README
/usr/share/doc/unclutter/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/unclutter.1.gz
/usr/bin/unclutter
```

[image]

-> The /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90unclutter :

```
# /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90unclutter
# This file is sourced by Xsession(5), not executed.

if [ -e /etc/default/unclutter ]
then
        . /etc/default/unclutter
fi

if [ -x /usr/bin/unclutter ] && [ "${START_UNCLUTTER}" = "true" ]
then
        /usr/bin/unclutter ${EXTRA_OPTS} &
fi
```

--> The /etc/default/unclutter :

```
# /etc/default/unclutter - configuration file for unclutter

# Set this option to 'true' if you want to start unclutter
# automagically after X has been started for a user.
# Otherwise, set it to 'false'.
START_UNCLUTTER="true"

# Options passed to unclutter, see 'man unclutter' for details.
EXTRA_OPTS="-idle 1 -root"
```

---> The configuration file is the /etc/default/unclutter.

Purging the unclutter...

Comment: Unclutter was installed by default on my install of Kubuntu 12.04 beta 1. I used the Alt installer. I looked at the man page before posting my question. Unfortunately, nothing I have seen gives me any clue as to where unclutter puts the config file. That's my question, basically. Where is the config file?

Answer (score 1):

Unclutter is currently a dependency on kubuntu-full, not kubuntu-desktop, so it does get installed by default if you want the full Kubuntu experience and install that package. I think this dependency should be removed.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it. I had installed kubuntu-full without realizing all the consequences of it.